# Electron Cash Wallet now suddenly not accepting password?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cash, electron-cash

So, i installed this software yesterday. Set up everything, created a password, TESTED the password, wrote down the generation seed.

I logged in this morning to check that the coin i sent to this wallet was actually there. I puchased this last night. Fair enough, the transaction was showing, so it had taken.

Went back twenty minutes later just to double check the amount; and now, Electron Cash Wallet will not accept the password.

I have tried numerous checks - keybaord configuration error, mistyped keys - but i noted down and tested the password twice yesterday on setup. There is either something wrong with this wallet software, or something has gone wrong in the interm twenty minutes.

Checked that i downloaded the correct executable file, and this was downloaded from https://www.electroncash.org/.

Has anybody out there had issues like this with the Electron Cash Wallet? I have looked for some form of support but the website offers nothing. Don't believe that the generation seed will help either as this would only regenerate a new wallet unless I am wrong? Can't actually help me get into my own wallet, the password for which is now no longer functioning.

Comment: This has been flagged as off-topic as being about a customer relationship. Please note that this close reason is meant to be used on questions non-public communication between companies and customers. Electron Cash appears to be a non-profit open source project and does not fall under that rule.

Comment: I don't understand what this means. What does 'used on questions non-public communication between companies and customers' mean? Does not make any sense I'm afraid.

Comment: That was not meant for you, but for another user that had flagged this question as off-topic which I didn't think was a correct assessment. :)

Comment: Are you sure that you've chosen the right wallet file?

Comment: There was only one wallet file.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Electron Cash myself, so I can't speak to that effect, but actually, the generation seed is exactly what would help you here. The seed words are a human readable representation of the master private key. This allows them to function as a backup of your wallet. When you use the same seed words, you'll regenerate the same wallet.